# Replace all occurrences of double quotes except if followed by or preceded by comma using sed command

Tags: sed, string

I want to replace all occurrences of `"` with `^"` in my file, except when the `"` are followed or preceded by a comma (`,`) or if they are at the beginning of the line

i.e. -

```
"InvoiceA","Doe,John",12/01/2016,200,"Comment on Invoice: "Customer X purchased item Z from store C named "Abc" on "03/04/2016""
```

Should be converted to -

```
"InvoiceA","Doe,John",12/01/2016,200,"Comment on Invoice: ^"Customer X purchased item Z from store C named ^"ABC^" on ^"03/04/2016^""
```

Comment: Why not **use standard CSV format?**  That would mean doubling the "quoted" quotation marks to indicate a literal quotation mark.  Also, you appear to be missing a trailing double quote character at the very end of your line.

Comment: @Wildcard 
Unfortunately, I am not getting such csv file, hence want to convert using scripting to make it easier for data loading -
Thanks corrected 
"InvoiceA","Doe,John",12/01/2016,200,"Comment on Invoice: "Customer X purchased item Z from store C named "Abc" on "03/04/2016""

Should be converted to -

"InvoiceA","Doe,John",12/01/2016,200,"Comment on Invoice: ^"Customer X purchased item Z from store C named ^"ABC^" on ^"03/04/2016^""

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post corrections in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you also want to leave quote characters
at the end of the line untouched (as shown in your example). 
You can do this with

```
sed 's/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1^"\2/g'
```

This looks for strings of three consecutive characters, as follows:

1. A character other than a comma (`,`),
2. A double quote (`"`), and
3. A character other than a comma,

and replaces them with

1. The first character,
2. `^"`, and
3. The third character.

This will not work on multiple consecutive quoted quote characters; e.g.,

```
…200,"Purchase at store named "" on Tuesday"
```

P.S. Did you know that your example has unbalanced quotes?

```
"Comment on Invoice: "Customer X purchased item Z from store C named "Abc" on "03/04/2016""
                     ↑                                               ↑   ↑    ↑          ↑
```